# Trim double value in C++

Tags: c++

How can I remove the uesless '0' for double value in C++?

```
double dVal = 6.606000;
double dOut;

dOut = someMethod(dVal); // dOut = 6.606;
```

thanks.

Comment: Please read up on [IEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008).

Comment: double value doesn't need to be trimmed of trailing zeros. It's essentially stored as a digit in computer memory. A string representation of "6.606000" can be trimmed but that would be another story.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is based on a misunderstanding.

If you have 10 pencils or 10.0 pencils, the pencils are the same. There's no way to take 10.0 pencils and give back 10 pencils. -- They're the same pencils. In pencils, "10.0" and "10" are the same.

The zeroes are not in the stored value, they're just presented that way for output. The way "6.606000" is represented as a double is identical to the way "6.606" would be represented.